# Hard disk motor as a generator - controlling torque/rotation speed

Tags: control, generator

I'm a mechanical engineer, currently working on a project concerning wind turbines: I want to use an hard disk spindle motor (4 pins) as my generator. Since I want to do wake experiments, I'd like to control the rotation speed of the turbine, and if possible directly from the motor.

I've searched for it and I think spindle motors are simply 3 coiled motors, so I was wondering if you guys had any idea about how to control the braking force of the motor (and thus the torque/rotation speed)?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Did you test the maximum break torque with a shortcut over all pins? Is this sufficient at all to slow down your repeller?

Comment: @Jens I've now measured the torque with a shortcut and yes, that should be able to stop the repeller (its a very small wind turbine). I've read I should try a dumpload, if you have any comments on it.

Comment: Connect a 3 phase rectifier with 6 diodes (Schottky preferred) and a test load of 100 ohm to get a first impression of maximum voltage and power range.

Comment: @Jens I've done the rectifier, I've connected it correctly and under a certain rotation speed (that is the maximum), the measurements are 0.17 A for 1.25 V of tension.

Comment: OK, fine. What do you want to do with these enourmous 200 mW? You could charge a small battery. The interesting thing is to find the optimum load current where U * I has the maximum. There are less losses in the rectifier at lower current and higer voltage. What are your ideas?

Comment: I don't really mind about where those watts go. My goal is to control the rotation speed of the turbine, and if possible, electrically. It would be hard to do it mechanically because I have to measure the mechanical torque, and adding friction anywhere else than in the motor would make it unmeasurable.
My idea was to control this speed with the electical load on the motor : I don't really know if it is possible or not tho

Comment: Do you need a closed loop control with fixed rpm target or just a manually controlled break? This makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Jens A manually controlled break would be the perfect thing, but if you think it's really hard to conceive, I'll take the second solution.
Thanks a lot for your help and your time by the way.

Comment: A wire wound power potentiometer or rheostat (2 W type) as variable load behind the rectifier may be sufficient. If not, we must think a bit more :)